# How to center an input[type=text] while leaving all the other elements uncenterred?

Tags: html, css

I have another small problem with centering elements. I thought about the previous questions that I've asked, but I can't seem to find the answer on this problem. I have the following example code to demonstrate my problem.

```
<div id="main" style="width: 960px;">
    <form>
        <label>Test</label>
        <input type="text" value="Test" id="inputfield" />
    </form>
    ....
</div>
```

Now I tried to treat it as a block-element using width and margin to position it correctly, but somehow it failed. Do I need to use an id field or is it recommanded that I put a div around every input text field (using `#main input[type=text]{...}`)?

Comment: Do you want to center it in the middle of the window, or in the middle of the white space that remains to the right of the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, the best way would be assigning specific rule as per the id `#inputfiled`

Add this in the CSS <sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/uMLQV/2/)</sup>

```
#inputfield { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Relying on attribute selectors like `input[type="text"]` is very risky in terms of cross-browser compatibility.

---

#### Updates

In case you want to center all input elements, but not other, you can use a name selector

```
input,select,textarea { /* These three elements round up all the input types */
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: @TJ. Actually It will, I seemed to have linked the wrong demo. Check again

Comment: @TJ. As the forms expands to the 100% of the body, there is no need to define as specific width to the element.

Comment: I just tested this and you're absolutely right! +1 for this solution.

Comment: I see and would you suggest me using classes if all my input fields need to be centerred?

Comment: @Snowflake, On that case use name selector like `input { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

[when centering this way](http://jsfiddle.net/uMLQV/), you need to add `width`

```
input{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
}​
```

Comment: What is the difference between inline-block and block?

Comment: `inline-block` acts like an `inline` (elements beside another) but gives you advantages of the `block`: adding dimensions (width and height), and having top and bottom margins and padding to take effect (top and bottom margins and padding don't affect position in `inline` elements).

Comment: @Snowflake, `block` tends to take the entire width available, where as `inline-block` takes only the size of the elements it has got.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css and make sure you add a width.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #inputfield {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```